# Chromecast app is not listed in Chromecast's apps page

Tags: android, google-play, chromecast

I integrated chromecast support to my Android application. 
Published it (changed status to Published).
Then I changed to "YES" section

> LISTING DETAILS
>
> Allow users to discover your app on Google properties such as
>   chromecast.com/apps
>
> NOTE: Apps are only listed once they are published

It was about 2 weeks ago. And I still don't see my application at the Chromecast apps page.

What can I do for listing my application there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please contact me via our Help Center:

https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us

and provide the email address used to register your Google Cast Developer Account and your app ID and I'll investigate.

Regards,
Adam H.